# Sweave won't create PNG images

Tags: sweave, png

Up to this morning Sweave() was regularly creating images in png format (I used `png=T`  as an argument).

At some point Sweave would no longer create any PNG image (this is a problem for me 'cause running MikTeX I found tricky managing pdf or eps pics).

Now I have checked over any possible modification and inadvertences in the .Rnw file ultimately even retrieving files from my usb that used to work normally yesterday, I have shut off R session many times to reset possible unwanted changes to the settings, `result= nothing`.

It is like all of a sudden Sweave would not work properly anymore. I know this does not make sense, in fact is quite odd thing happening to me since!

Any suggestion is appreciated

PS: Only thing I've been thinking to is me messing around with `getOption(default=)`  and `option(default=)`, but as I said I relaunched brand new R sessions several times to be sure normal settings were restored.

---

My R platform is:

```
R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31) 
i386-pc-mingw32 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] xtable_1.5-6    AICcmodavg_1.14 nlme_3.1-96     aod_1.2        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.11.1    lattice_0.18-8
```

I run on MiKTeX 2.9.

Consider this trivial example:

```
% .Rnw file

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{Sweave}

\SweaveOpts{keep.source=TRUE}

\begin{document}

\title{INTERNAL REPORT}
\date{}

\author{\textbf{Federico Bonofiglio}}

\maketitle

<<echo=F>>=

options(prompt=" ", continue= " ")

<<>>=

x<-rnorm(500,mean=3)

mean(x)

@

\begin{figure}

<<fig=T>>=

plot(x)

@

\caption(ciao)
\end{figure}

@

\end{document}
```

and the R code is:

```
setwd("C:\\your folder")


Sweave("prova",png= T, pdf=F)


library(tools)

texi2dvi("prova.tex",pdf=T)
```

NOTE that the Sweave command above has been working nicely for me up to this morning (i.e. producing PNG files *and* not EPS or PDF ones).

I'm very puzzled and frustrated. It seems like Sweave() has forgot about the PNG option.

Comment: Could you add a minimal example illustrating this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question have unclear passages, e.g. "....I ahve shut off R session many times to reset possible unwanted changes to the settings....., result= nothing." Could you please clarify your question and provide  a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: This is very close to being off topic, (namely an R problem rather than a Sweave/TeX problem) unless you can provide more information.

Comment: Your minimal document has no `@` after your `options` command and an extra `@` at the end.